# Equivalent resistance between B and D? the resistors are all equal

Tags: electricity

i already know the answer its 5R/6 , but i don't know the method

i tried delta-star conversion but i always make mistakes and find a wrong result

its a test at home i hope you can solve it for me as quick as possible , thanks

[image: i want to solve the equivalent resistance between B and D]

Comment: "solve it for me as quick as possible" won't happen. Show what you've tried! Maybe we can see your mistakes and help you out. Hint: the editor here has a rather convenient circuit drawing tool. Use it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is self admitted to be a test problem with a request for answer.

Comment: @MouadSama Please be professional and use proper punctuation and grammar on this site, it makes you look educated to other users.

Comment: @laptop2d did i make any grammatical or punctuation mistake ? i don't know why you judge me for this ,if you can't help me to solve this problem you can help me with your silence , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stretch out the circuit to show all of the series and parallel combinations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRjxV0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can see that because of the symmetry between nodes "B" and "D", the vertical link between R11/R12 and R5/R6 carries no current and can be removed. The remaining calculation is straightforward. Transformations are not necessary.

\$\frac{5}{6}R\$ is NOT the correct answer, BTW.

Comment: but the answer must be 5R/6 !!! 
because in the problem it self asks for the method to use,answer is already written !!

Comment: i wanted to use delta-star transformation but it scrambled and i couldn't do it

Comment: I don't know where you got the problem (and its supposed answer), but the simulator says that I'm right and you're wrong. Set all of the resistors to 1 ohm, apply 1 volt across C and D. 1.412 A of current flows, which is NOT the value you would get if the resistance is 5/6 ohms.

Comment: If you add a voltage-source between B and D, the electric potential of the point C is exactly the middle point of the point B and D. So are the potential of the point F and G,which  means you can connect them with wires and still have the same equivalent resisitance between B and D.

So connect the C, F & G with wires, then find out the equivalent resistance between B and C then double it.

The equivalence between B & C (after connect the C, F & G) is easy to find out. It’s R(bc)//R(bf)//[R(bh)+R(hg)//R(hf)] =(5/12)r.

So the equivalence between B & D is (5/6)r.

Comment: But that isn't the question you originally asked. The title says, *"Equivalent resistance between **C** and D?"* That's the question I answered.

Comment: oh sorry !! i thought i corrected the question

Comment: can you do the stretched circuit between B and D please !!

Comment: No. B and D is trivially symmetric, as you have already worked out. You've seen it done once, I'm sure you can work it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Attack this problem by doing the easiest simplification first, then seeing where you're at and repeating.  Eventually you simplify the circuit to a single resistor between C and D.

For example, three really obvious simplifications pop out immediately from what you show.  Hint: Look for pairs of resistors where the node between them connects to nothing else.  These can be combined to their series equivalent.